# Sort date ascending in Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am new for programming and also C# language. I want to sort  rows in C# `Datatable` by date as ascending order. have any special method for do this simply way? Thanks.

Comment: use ORDER BY in the query

Comment: Show your `sql-server` query.

Comment: you can use sql-server ORDER BY or use sort facility of gridview.

Comment: Show some of your code please

Comment: You mention list, so I assume you are populating a listview?  If so, why not try this alternative.  http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html  It is very powerful and allows you to sort, filter, search and do many more things very quickly, easily and all out of the box with no additional coding required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all read data from you SQL to DataTable object.
When you have filled DataTable you can sort data like this:

```
table.DefaultView.Sort = "columnName asc";
```